# Подобрать формат даты для SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, simpledateformat

Есть такая запись в БД

Sun Mar 25 19:00:00 MSK 2018

как подобрать правильно формат для SimpleDateFormat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Общий подход примерно такой:

1. Заходим в документацию [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).
2. Изучаем таблицу со спецификаторами форматов.
3. Изучаем примеры.
4. Подбираем похожие части:

   ```
   EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy
   ```